# Application is being closed when page type for printer changed in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

Iam developing a windows application using C#.NET and Crystal Reports.

Development Environment is IDE : Visual Studio 2005, OS : Windows Server 2003

A network printer was selected as default printer for the development purpose.

When changing the printer or page type(A3, A4 etc.) int the ".rpt" file the IDE is being closed.

Some times it is showing the error "division by zero" with some hexadecimal numbers.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

1) Firstly install Microsoft XPS Document Writer.

2) Set Microsoft XPS Document Writer as default printer.